# Query Django model using name from another model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I'm building a project that involves a list of people and the transactions they've made. Each person will have their own profile with x amount of transactions.

My database, so far, consists of two models:

One to define a person

```
class Person (models.Model):
    """
    A person
    """

    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

One to associate a transaction each person made.

```
class Purchase (models.Model):
    """
    A purchase for each person
    """
    person_id = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    purchase_description = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True)
```

I determined this would be a many-to-one database relationship because some people might make the same transaction.

Now, I can make pages for each person, showing their name in the header. What I'd like to do is show the transactions made to that particular person. How can this be done? Here's what my view.py file looks like:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Person, Purchase

def load_person(request, name):

    person = Person.objects.get(name=name)

    # name = Purchase.objects.filter(purchase)

    context = {
        'name': name
        # 'purchase': purchase
    }

    return render(request, 'pages/person.html', context)
```

Here's the url associated to the query in my url.py file.

```
url(r'^project/(?P<name>[-\w]+)/$', views.load_person),
```

Comment: Using `person_id` as you field name, in your database you will get `person_id_id` because django uses the `Person` object to query and map it to the object's pk (or id). So when you create a model class, you should use (in this case) `person` which will reflect in your DB as `person_id`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I wondered why I saw person_id_id in the error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
person = Person.objects.get(name=name)
purchases = Purchase.objects.filter(person_id=person)
```

Sounds like you just started using django, there are several things that are not best practice, they are:

1. You don't need to define `id` in `Person`, django will define it for you.
2. Try not to use `person_id` as field name, use `person` instead. Django model is not relational database design, think of the models as separate entities.

Comment: I am new to Django and didn't know it was bad practice to include an ID field. I appreciate the feedback and made the changes. Your suggestion as well as returning a string and creating a for loop in my template gave me the results I needed. Thanks for your help!